# Developing Firefox plugins?

Tags: firefox, programming-languages, plugins

What language(s) do I need to know to develop plugins/extensions for Firefox? Also, any useful tools (as far as IDE or SDKs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML, XUL, Javascript, C (if you're forced to use XPCOM).

Pick your favorite editor.

Answer (score 5):

Plugins and extensions are two very different things. Plugins are like Java, Adobe Reader, etc. Extensions are the more common of the two and typically what you find on addons.mozilla.org.

mozdev.org has some good resources for creating extensions. You don't really need an IDE or SDK's as it is primarily JavaScript unless you want to implement something like XPCOM.

developer.mozilla.org is also a good resource.

Comment: note for the curious: XPCOM is Firefox's basic interface with the OS (such as Windows).

Comment: Uh, no, XPCOM is not Firefox's basic interface with the OS.  It's technically "cross platform COM" and it's just a set of interfaces to do various things.  Yes, some of that has to deal with the operating system, but the vast majority of it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox uses **XUL**, a anguage ***similar to HTML***. If you know HTML, XUL will be easy to learn. In fact, Firefox is *completely made in XUL*.

Take a look at this link inside Firefox: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

And basically an add-on is like a much more powerful web page (actually you *can make an application based in XUL just like Firefox is*... and use XULRunner to run it on *any OS* (and even from the web!), with all of Gecko's rendering power for free).

Links:

- http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_joy_of_xul

Answer (score 0):

You would want to have an idea of how `markup` languages work. The development of extensions or add-ons is done in `XUL` and `XPCOM` (I am assuming you did **not** mean plugins, pardon me I am wrong and this answer then would be only half of what you want to know.)

This is a [handy guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/firefox_addons_dev_guide) to developing add-ons from Mozilla's website.